# How to show only first error with Microsoft Typescript compiler?

Tags: typescript

Typescript displays all found errors during compilation, and due to type system one typo can easily produce hundreds of errors, forcing me to scroll output to beginning on each compilation failure. I'm using `webpack` with `ts-loader`, is it any way to stop compilation on first error like most compilers can do?

Comment: Have you solved this problem? It seems reasonable to pipe into less or some filter for first n console lines...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is unfortunately *no*.

1. TypeScript compiler does not have an option for this. The [source](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/tsc.ts#L11) [code](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/tsc.ts#L96) shows that all errors are reported at once.
2. `ts-loader` does not have an option for this too. However, it seems [the feature can added](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/blob/master/index.ts#L100) by a simple patch.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a real solution to make the TypeScript compiler break after the first error, but if you just want to have less cruft to scroll through in your console, then `tsc | head -n 5` will return the first 5 lines of output, which is more-or-less the first error.